# AlarmManager not starting broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I'm working on a project which requires to check flag status from my database every 2 mins but my broadcast receiver class is not triggering .

Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
int year,month,day,hour,min;

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            mystart();

        }
    });

    Intent i = new Intent(this,myBackgroundChecker.class);
    pendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);





}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void mystart(){
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour  = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    min   = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    month+=1;
    min+=1;
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+hour+min+" day: "+day+ "month  :"+month+"Year  : "+year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min+1);

    int repeat = 1000*60*2;

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), repeat, pendingIntent);

}
```

}

myBackgroundChecker.java

```
public class myBackgroundChecker extends BroadcastReceiver{

static MediaPlayer mp;
InputStream is=null;
String result="";
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(arg0, R.raw.alert);

    mp.setLooping(true);

    //myDb m = new myDb();


    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("flag","0"));

    Toast.makeText(arg0, "service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //m.execute();
    //First reading if 1 or not!
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.102/get.php");
        //httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
//convert response to string
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result=sb.toString();
        Log.e("myTag", result);
       // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}

    if(result.equals("1")){
        mp.start();
    }


    // after trigering alarm setting to 0

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.102/set.php");
        httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
//convert response to string
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result=sb.toString();
        Log.e("myTag", result);
       // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}







}
```

Manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.remotealarm_client"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.remotealarm_client.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.remotealarm_client.myBackgroundChecker">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">

            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: You're pushing the initial alarm time to next month. - `month+=1;`

Comment: @MikeM. But the indexing of month starts from 0 so incremented 1

Comment: Think about that for a second. You're reading the month from a current `Calendar`, adding one to it, then setting it back on the `Calendar`.

Comment: @MikeM. I removed that line but nothing changes :/

Comment: How are you determining that the Receiver isn't running? Does it work upon rebooting? Are you sure it's just not crashing before your `Toast`? You should a at least add a log print at the beginning of `onReceive()`. Also, your initial alarm will be around two minutes on the future, btw, since you're adding one to the minute twice.

Comment: Actually, now that I look again, it won't work upon rebooting anyway, 'cause you don't have the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes i tried rebooting but it didn't trigger  , i added a log message at the beginning of onReceive() but its not showing.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanx for pointing out ill add it , however its not entering onReceive()

Comment: Well, the first thing I would do is to test the Receiver directly with `sendBroadcast()`. Then try setting an exact alarm for now. Then check the resulting `Calendar`'s time, and compare to now. Then try the repeating alarm. Etc.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanx for the help , ill try it :)

Comment: Oop, I see another big problem. You're passing a null `PendingIntent` to `AlarmManager`. `getBroadcast()` is a `static` method in `PendingIntent` that returns the `PendingIntent` that you want. It doesn't actually initialize the instance it's called on. That is, assign its return to `pendingIntent`. -- `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);`

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you so much , Its working :D

Comment: No problem. Sorry I didn't notice that right off. I'll post an answer with our findings, here in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to correct in your posted code. First, for your `BroadcastReceiver` to be delivered the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, you'll need to add the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission. Also note that, since 3.1, your app will have to be launched at least once after installation to bring it out of the *stopped* state in order to get that broadcast.

Second, in figuring the initial time for that alarm, you're a month ahead. It's true that `Calendar`'s months are zero-based, but you're using the `Calendar`'s zero-based value, so adding one to it is pushing it to next month.

Lastly, the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` method is a `static` method that returns the requested `PendingIntent`. It doesn't initialize the instance it's called on (which, incidentally, would cause a `NullPointerException` in this case, if it did). This means you've been passing a null `PendingIntent` to `AlarmManager`, so that's obviously not going to do anything. Change that line to call the method on the class, and to assign the return to your field.

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
```